# How do I tell jQuery to run a function on two specific web pages only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to Jquery and have been looking for the solution to this issue for a while - 
I'm using the following at the top of my Jquery file to restrict to only work on the home page

```
   if (top.location.pathname === '/') 

        {
```

How can I change this to also work on the /About page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you want to use an "or"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to do this

```
if (top.location.pathname === '/' || top.location.pathname ==='/About' ) 
{
     // Your code goes here
}
```

Comment: hopefully the OP does not have querystrings. ;)

Comment: Great that works =) I had been messing around with it for a few hours! ( end of a very long day ) , Thanks allot